# React.js infinite loop when setting dependent state variable inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, compilation, infinite-loop

I'm building a visual graph editor in React using [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/). I store the nodes in state as `nodes`. The user can drag and drop element on the graph, modifying the `nodes` array.

When `nodes` is updated, I kick off a long-running compilation step. Once the compilation step completes, I **need to update the `nodes` array with data from the compilation result.** When I do this, it triggers an infinite loop of compilation.

Here's a shortened version of the compile `useEffect` hook:

```
const [compiling, setCompiling] = useState(false);
const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setCompiling(true);
  longRunningCompile(nodes, stateA, stateB, stateC, stateD).then(result => {

    setNodes(nodes.map(element => {
      /* merging of compile output and existing nodes */
    }));

    setCompiling(false);
  })
}, [nodes, stateA, stateB, stateC, stateD]);
```

You can see above, because `nodes` is a dependency of the `useEffect`, and I call `setNodes` inside the `useEffect`, it re-triggers the compilation infinitely.

The re-compilation has several dependencies. One of them is the user can do something like add a new node (or modify an existing node). Paraphrasing UI element interactions:

```
<button onClick={() => setNodes([...nodes, { some new node }])}>
<button onClick={() => setStateA(...)}>
<button onClick={() => setStateB(...)}>
<button onClick={() => setStateC(...)}>
<button onClick={() => setStateD(...)}>
```

I've considered something like trying to juggle a "compiled" flag stored on a ref or the nodes to prevent infinite updates. I'm not sure if that would work. Is there a declarative way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `nodes` a dependency for `longRunningCompile`? Can we see an example of how these dependencies are referenced and used within the `useEffect` hook's callback scope?

Comment: as a general remarks, you are modifying nodes in the useEffect where the nodes are as dependency : this will always create an infinite loop. You probably have to handle the flow differently without a useEffect. Right now you are saying If I nodes are changed, change the nodes again. Couldn't you just trigger a function for each node change that do the compilation, without useEffect ?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, `nodes` is passed to the compilation function.

Comment: What are the *actual* conditions in which you need/want this `longRunningCompile` component to run? Do you want it to run if/when `nodes` updates alone, or is it more when any of the other stateX values changes and you just want to reference the current `nodes` value?

Comment: @DrewReese the other state variables are arguments to the compilation function, I want to recompile when any of the dependencies change.

Comment: "I want to recompile when any of the dependencies change" - I'm asking for what you consider *actual* dependencies for the `longRunningCompile` function (*not necessarily a dependency for the `useEffect` hook*). I feel like we've not enough context to understand your use case, i.e. what your goal is. You obviously can't have `nodes` as a hook dependency since you are updating that state, so understanding what the code is supposed to do may help us help you tweak the code so `nodes` isn't a hook dependency any more.